# Outline of bar going through other bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

For some reason the outline has continued through some of the other bars, I'm not really sure why. This is the code I used to make it.

```
graph <- ggplot(data = parrots2, aes(x = Reared, y = Scores, fill = Variables)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), color = "black") + labs(x = "Rearing style", y = "Frequency of scores")
        graph
```

My graph:

[image: My graph]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: This said: The issue is most likely that you have multiple observations or rows for some combinations of `Reared` and `Variables`. Hence, you end up with multiple bars which are plotted on top of each other.